# Form en varias páginas, problema con los initial values (flutter)

Tags: formularios, flutter

Muy buenas, estoy empezando a programar en flutter y tengo un problema con un formulario que he creado en varias pantallas. En ambas tengo un selector hecho con CupertinoPicker, en la primera pantalla va de 0 a 10, con un valor inicial de 4, y en la segunda va de 20 a 40, con un valor inicial de 28. El problema es que al elegir un valor en el primer selector se modifica también la segunda pantalla, es decir, si elijo "2" en el primer selector, al ir a la segunda pantalla en lugar de aparecer seleccionado el "28", aparece seleccionado el "22", y al revés. 
Imagino que es algo que se queda guardado al ir de una a otra y que no estoy seteando correctamente, pero no se qué puede ser...
Este es el código:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

class OnBoarding extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<OnBoarding> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Onboarding'),
      ),
      body: Container(
         padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
         color: Colors.white,
         child: FormWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class FormWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FormWidgetState createState() => _FormWidgetState();
}

class _FormWidgetState extends State<FormWidget> {

  int _stepNumber = 1;
  int num1 = 4;
  int num2 = 28;

  void saveData(BuildContext context) {

    _formKey.currentState.save();

    print(num1.toString());
    print(num2.toString());
  }

  void nextPage(BuildContext context) {
    saveData(context);
    setState(() {
      if (_stepNumber == 1)
        _stepNumber = 2;
      else
        _stepNumber = 1;
    });
  }


  Column formOneBuilder(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)),
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Text("STEP 1")
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 200,
          child: new CupertinoPicker(
            scrollController: FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem: num1),
            itemExtent: 70,
            onSelectedItemChanged: (int val) {
              print('num1: $num1');
              print('Selected: $val');
              num1 = val;
            },
            children: <Widget>[
              for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                  child: Text(
                    i.toString(),
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),

        Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Text('Next'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    nextPage(context);
                  } ,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }


  Column formTwoBuilder(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.red)),
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Text("STEP 2"),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 200,
          child: new CupertinoPicker(
            scrollController: FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem: 28),
            itemExtent: 70,
            onSelectedItemChanged: (int val) {
              print('num2: $num2');
              print('Selected: $val');
              num2 = (20 + val);
            },
            children: <Widget>[
              for (int i = 20; i < 40; i++)
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                  child: Text(
                    i.toString(),
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Text('Previous'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    nextPage(context);
                  } ,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    switch (_stepNumber) {
      case 1:
          return Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child:
                this.formOneBuilder(context),
          );
          break;

      case 2:
        return Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child:
                this.formTwoBuilder(context),
        );
        break;
    }
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes algunos errores, el primero es que estás usando num2 o 28 como valor seleccionado, pero el `initialItem` no espera eso, sino espera el índice seleccionado, por lo que cambialo por 0 por ejemplo.

```dart
int num2 = 0;
...
 scrollController: FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem: num2),
```

Otro error es que estás sacando los widgets del widget tree al hacer el cambio de `_stepNumber` , te recomiendo usar el `IndexedStack` widget para cambiar de contenido.

Quedaría así:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: IndexedStack(
        index: _stepNumber - 1,
        children: <Widget>[
          this.formOneBuilder(context),
          this.formTwoBuilder(context),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: mil gracias diegoveloper!efectivamente con tus consejos funciona perfecto!